# What does "WHERE clause just after OPTIONAL MATCH" claause means?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example,

```
// create data
WITH RANGE(1,5) AS ages
UNWIND ages AS age CREATE(k:Kid{age:age}) RETURN k;
MATCH(ks:Kid) WHERE ks.age > 2
WITH COLLECT(ks) AS ks
UNWIND ks AS k
FOREACH (n IN RANGE(1, k.age) | CREATE(k)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy{size:n}));

// show all data
MATCH(k:Kid)
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) RETURN *;

// delete all data
MATCH(k:Kid)
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) DETACH DELETE k, t RETURN *;
```

Then submit some queries.

```
MATCH(k:Kid) // query No.1
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size = 4
WITH k
WHERE t.size = 4
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT k);
=> 2 // correct

MATCH(k:Kid) // query No.2
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size IS NOT NULL
WITH k
WHERE t.size IS NOT NULL
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT k);
=> 3 // correct

MATCH(k:Kid) // query No.3
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size IS NULL
WITH k
WHERE t.size IS NULL
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT k);
=> 5 // not correct. i think it should be 2.
```

Then after removing "WHERE clause just after OPTIONAL MATCH", submit those queries.
No.1,2 are same result and No.3 is not same.

What I want to know is Why does only query No.3 get different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to understand what `OPTIONAL MATCH` does, for a given node, it tries to find the matching nodes, via relationships, that match certain criteria (`WHERE` clause). If they are found it returns them, otherwise it gives  `null`. Now, there is one thing I need to point out, in your query:

```
MATCH(k:Kid) <-- Kids fetched here
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size IS NULL <-- Kids again fetched here not required
WITH k
WHERE t.size IS NULL
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT k);
```

You are fetching `Kid` nodes twice. The line
`OPTIONAL MATCH (k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size IS NULL`, basically tries to fetch all the `Kid` and `Toy` nodes, however, if for a `kid` there is no `toy` whose `size` is `null`, it will give `null` as `toy` value. So when     `WITH k WHERE t.size IS NULL` it evaluates to true for every kid since `toy` it self is `null`. Now the fix, is simple, just remove `WHERE` clause from the `optional match`, first fetch all the `toys`, linked to a `kid` and then filter them in `with` clause.

```
MATCH(k:Kid) // query No.3
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH (k)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy)
WITH k
WHERE t.size IS NULL
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT k);
```

For more clarity, just try running this query on your system:

```
MATCH(k:Kid) // query No.3
WITH k
OPTIONAL MATCH(k:Kid)-[:HAS]->(t:Toy) WHERE t.size IS NULL
RETURN k, t
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Charchit Kapoor.
So, the point is that if we use "IS NULL" condition for related nodes(Toy) on "WHERE" clause just after "OPTIONAL MATCH" clause, cypher returns null for all related nodes.

Comment: Yes, if a node does not matches the filter a null will be returned for that node.